# Workflow management tool suggestion for software-architecture design

Tags: python, redis, architecture, rabbitmq, celery

I have the following workflow used in my project.
[image]

1. Each task (Task A,B,C,D) is distributed and run separately in their own container.
2. These tasks use `celery-rabbitmq` for message passing and triggering next task.
3. Each task receives a list of events to be processed (event 1,2...). These are manually triggered at any time, not cron jobs.
4. When Task A's event-1 is complete it marks its state as done in redis. Meanwhile Task B polls redis every 2sec till it gets `done` state and triggers event-1. Same flow ahead for task C,D.
5. Task A now starts executing event-2, meanwhile Task B again waits for `done` state for event-2 in redis.
6. Above flow continues till all the events are processed in sequential order by every task.
   **Note: Each tasks' event-2 runs in the same python process as event-1 sharing all variables present in RAM. i.e. these are part of the same task**

Each task's code can be roughly equivalent to following:

```py
class TaskB:
    def __init__(eventlist):
        self.eventlist = eventlist
    
    def process():
        for event in self.eventlist:
           wait_for_taskA_event_complete_in_redis(event)
           process_event(event)
```

### Problem with this approach

1. Scaling is an issue. As number of tasks and eventlist grows, manually managing redis state  becomes messy, especially when there is some failure in between.

### Questions

1. I am not sure what this architecture design is called, any specific category it falls into ?
2. Are there any ready frameworks available to handle such kind of distributed flows ? Our primary goal would be to eliminate redis-based state handling and delegate it to framework's workflow management system.
3. Also, if anything be done to improvise in the current tech-stack itself ?

### P.S.

This might be a redundant question, but due to lack of my knowledge, I am not sure what exactly to search for, for these kind of issues (especially when i don't know what above arch is called.